# Install Python modules offline with all dependencies

Tags: python, module, pip, offline

I am trying to install requests-kerberos on an air-gapped network (pip doesn't work, no internet).

is there some way in which I can get all the dependencies for it and all of the dependencies for the dependencies in one "set" so I can move it to the air-gapped network. for example it has cryptography as a dependency and cryptography has setuptools_rust and more and more and the list doesn't end.

any ideas?

Comment: You could create a new virtualenv using the same version of Python, install your package in it with pip, and all the dependencies will be downloaded as well. You can then zip the whole thing up, throw it on a thumb drive, and copy it to the other computer.

Comment: ehhh, i don't know much about virtualenvs and how to use them... Maybe a different solutions like downloading all the files or something? or maybe an explanation?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+offline